# Overriding command in AWS Fargate task in AWS Step Function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-fargate, aws-step-functions

The aim is to have an AWS state machine that runs an AWS Fargate task with a custom command.
Per [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ecs.html), the command in the Docker image of the Fargate task may be overridden by having

```
"Overrides": {
    "ContainerOverrides": [{
        "Name": "container-name",
        "Command.$": "$.commands"
    }]
}
```

as one item of `"Parameters"`.
Note the `.$` after `Command`.

I want to build the state machine with AWS CDK.
Per [CDK Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions_tasks/EcsRunTask.html), I can pass a container override, see parameter `container_overrides`, which expects a sequence of values of type `ContainerOverride` as value.
In one such `ContainerOverride` I can specify the command to executed.
When I do that, I end up getting

```
"Overrides": {
    "ContainerOverrides": [{
        "Name": "container-name",
        "Command": ["$.commands"]
    }]
}
```

as one item of `"Parameters"`.
The key of the command item should include `.$` and the value shouldn't be a list.

My question is: how to parameterize `aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.EcsRunTask` such that the desired `"Parameters"` item is obtained.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question based on [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/9253#issuecomment-663893552) information.

Consider the objective to use AWS CDK to pass the items of the value of `{"command": ["arg1", "arg2"]}` as command line arguments to a Fargate task inside a step function task. This may be achieved as follows:

```
from aws_cdk import aws_stepfunctions, aws_stepfunctions_task

aws_stepfunctions_tasks.EcsRunTask(
    ...,
    container_overrides=[
        aws_stepfunctions_tasks.ContainerOverride(
           container_definition=aws_stepfunctions.StateMachine(...),
           command=aws_stepfunctions.JsonPath.list_at("$.command")
        )
    ],
    ...
)
```